# Linux: Get information/stats about storage network

Tags: linux, performance, storage, storage-area-network

I want to know as much info as possible about the SAN a linux server is connected to.  What commands will give me the most comprehensive view?   Simply knowing the WWN of LUNS doesn't do much for me.  I'd like to know make/model of SAN/disks (if possible), but more importantly speed and performance stats. What do you use for a quick and dirty assessment of your SAN performance (FC or iSCSI)?

Comment: Your storage may expose such data by SNMP or a similar protocol if you configure it.

Comment: Seems like you should maybe contact your storage administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask the SAN administrator. It's easier than guessing :) I mean, fdisk and dmesg will give you manufacturer info.

But the answer to this depends on the make/model of the storage array. NetApp != HDS != Lefthand != EMC

Can you give some more info about what you want to know?

If you need SAN specs and don't readily have access to the administrator, that's not a technical issue.

If you are connected and need to benchmark, that IS within your control. At that point, iozone, fio and iostat are your friends. Generate a load on the relevant LUN and measure its performance.

Comment: See my comment to Guy for context.

Answer (score 1):

I know how it's done AIX, but a quick google on Linux brought me the [sg3_utils package](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg3_utils.html). You want to send a SCSI inquiry. Each storage will have their own way of replying- my VSP, for example, embeds the LDEV address, array serial number, and a bunch of other useful information into its reply.

SCSI inquiries are a part of the SCSI protocol, meaning that it should work whether you use FC, FCoE, or iSCSI. That said, it sounds like you want more information than you'll likely get back. If you want to know something about the raid level, caching, or hostgroup settings, you'll probably need to get the data directly from the array.

Comment: Or just call his *Basil*.

Comment: Not every company is lucky enough to have a storage admin :) But yeah, whoever has the password to the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates that you are looking for far more than the command-line is suited for. Server monitoring tools like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.com/solutions/san-monitoring) and its derivatives [offer plugins](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Storage-Systems/SAN-and-NAS) for state-of-the-art SAN monitoring.

SolarWinds also offers a [Free SAN Monitor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/san_monitor/) that may be of interest.

In terms of getting this information from the SAN at a lower-level, for instanec using NSMP as @Florin mentions, we would need more information your SAN systems' architecture in order to make suggestions.

Comment: This spawned from a DBA in my company who has a Linux Server with MySQL on it which I rely on, but don;'t have control over.  I wanted to know what the storage subsystem was, but he didn't know and asked me how to find out.  I realized I had no short answer for him.

Comment: Ah, in this case a SCSI inquiry will tell you at least what type of storage it's using. From there, though, you'll need to contact whoever manages the storage, assuming it's a SAN.